# Generating a random number every time in a specific time interval in java

Tags: java, random, libgdx, runtime, textures

I have a method, that draws textures at runtime.

I generate a random number, that changes the height of the texture.

The problem is, that during runtime, all possible random numbers are being created and that the texture is shown with all kind of heights.

I generate a random number with:

```
Random r = new Random();
int low = 0;
int high = 30;
int result1 = r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
```

Here's my `drawTower()` method:

```
private void drawTower() {

    batcher.draw(AssetLoader.texture1, tower1.getX(), tower1.getY() + tower1.getHeight() - result1, 
           tower1.getWidth(), midPointY - (tower1.getHeight()));    
}
```

You can see that there is `result1`, which is the randomly generated number.

Now the **problem**: In my method `render()` I use that `drawTower()` method, which is the reason why all possible random numbers are being created.

How can I fix this issue? I thought **about generating a random number and after specific time interval, a new random number is being generated.** But I don't know how it's done.

```
public void render(float runTime) {

    Wizard wizard = myWorld.getWizard();

    // Fill the entire screen with black, to prevent potential flickering.
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Begin ShapeRenderer
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

    // Draw Background color
    shapeRenderer.setColor(55 / 255.0f, 80 / 255.0f, 100 / 255.0f, 1);
    shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, 136, midPointY + 66);

    // End ShapeRenderer
    shapeRenderer.end();

    // Begin SpriteBatch
    batcher.begin();      
    batcher.enableBlending(); 

    batcher.draw(AssetLoader.texture0,
            wizard.getX(), wizard.getY(), wizard.getWidth(), wizard.getHeight());

    // Draw Tower
    drawTower();

    // End SpriteBatch
    batcher.end();

}
```

Comment: Do you need a random height once (per application) or after a given period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object that provides a new randomly generated value at your desired interval and assign this object as a field in the class that contains the `drawTower` method. Note that this generator object needs to properly synchronized because one thread will be accessing the randomly generated value while another thread will be updating it:

```
public class TimedRandomNumberGenerator {

    private final AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger();
    private final Timer valueUpdater;

    public TimedRandomNumberGenerator(long updateRateInMs) {
        valueUpdater = new Timer();
        valueUpdater.schedule(createTimerTask(), 0, updateRateInMs);
    }

    private TimerTask createTimerTask() {
        return new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                value.set(generateNewValue());
            }
        };
    }

    private static int generateNewValue() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int low = 0;
        int high = 30;
        return r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value.intValue();
    }
}
```

In the class that contains the `drawTower` method (note that for this example, the update rate it set to `1000` milliseconds, but can be changed to whatever your desired period is):

```
public class SomeClass {

    private final TimedRandomNumberGenerator generator = new TimedRandomNumberGenerator(1000);

    private void drawTower() {
        batcher.draw(
            AssetLoader.texture1,
            tower1.getX(), 
            tower1.getY() + tower1.getHeight() - generator.getValue(),
            tower1.getWidth(), midPointY - (tower1.getHeight())
        );    
    }
}
```

The synchronicity of `TimedRandomNumberGenerator` is captured in the use of `AtomicInteger`. This protects the randomly generated value from multiple readers and multiple writers (one writer in this case: The `TimedRandomNumberGenerator` itself). The `createTimerTask` method is just a convenience method, as the `TimerTask` class is not a functional interface (and therefore cannot be replaced with a lambda expression). The `valueUpdater.schedule` method call in the constructor is what schedules the random number to be updated once the desired period of time has expired.

Comment: Wow, what a professional answer! Thank you very much. You made me smile after I desperately tried to find a solution for hours!

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 Glad to help